# What are the best decks for beginners?

Tags: hearthstone

All decks, which I saw on the Web, where created in the assumption that you have every card in the game. Is there a deck for beginners? The decks, which used basic or cheap cards.

To formulate the question more precisely - **what are the winner decks among the decks, which use only free, common and rare cards?**

Comment: Use websites like Heartpwn to look at decks. Mostly they are the same like any other website which will show you decks which you need to have most cards. Sadly Hearthstone becomes "Pay to Win" at this point. I can link you this warrior deck that is the closest to using basic and rare cards.

http://www.hearthpwn.com/decks/59805-worgen-freeman-easy-laddering-on-a-budget

Comment: @Charkz Sorry, but Hearthstone is definitely not a pay to win game!

Comment: A discussion which has never been there before. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trump has listed some free to play decks for this purpose and also played them himself. You also might want to check out his [site](https://sites.google.com/site/trumpdecks/freetoplay) for further explanations or watch his [twitch channel](http://www.twitch.tv/trumpsc).

[image: mage deck]
[image: shaman deck]
[image: warlock deck]

Answer (score 5):

The Warlock Zoo deck is commonly considered to be the cheapest competitive deck. It costs around 1200 dust to craft, the latest version from Reynad which I'm currently trying out has the following decklist:

[image]

Most of the minions used in this deck are pretty good on their own, crafting them won't lose you that much even if you don't continue to use this specific deck later. Doomguard is rather specific to this deck, but I wouldn't try to play this deck without it.

Here's a video of Reynad explaining the idea behind the deck, there are also some example games in the same channel:

If you just started playing and don't want to or can't craft the entire deck, I'd recommend to start with a variant of [Trump's Free Mage](https://sites.google.com/site/trumpdecks/freetoplay). The Mage class has very good class cards like Fireball and Water Elemental, and Polymorph can help a lot against the big legendaries which you'll inevitably encounter at some point.

[image]

You can leave out the more expensive stuff and replace it, the deck will be a bit weaker but it should still work. I'd craft the Harvest Golems and the Azure Drake first, they're really useful in many decks. I also like the Amani Berserkers, and they're especially good with a Mage that can easily enrage them with the Hero power.

Answer (score -4):

if you really want to do well I would suggest go for a defensive deck made up of a lot of taunt creatures and a lot of spell cards, this is my plan till i work my way up to unlocking all the basic cards for each character and it seems to be working ;)